# Java: How to handle internally an exception if was thrown by the main method executed in an Optional?

Tags: java, exception

About Java `Optional` having the following template

```
Optional.ofNullable(executeMethodA())
        .ifPresent(() -> executeMethodB());
```

Here 2 scenarios:

- If `executeMethodA()` returns `null` then `ifPresent` is **not** executed
- If `executeMethodA()` returns **not** `null` then `ifPresent` is executed

Until all is OK. But what about if `executeMethodA()` throws an `Exception`?

Is there something like

```
Optional.ofNullable(executeMethodA())
        .ifException(ex -> handleException(ex)) <---
        .ifPresent(() -> executeMethodB());
```

or

```
Optional.ofNullable(executeMethodA())
        .ifException(ex -> { try/catch block}) <---
        .ifPresent(() -> executeMethodB());
```

The purpose is avoid

```
try {
       Optional.ofNullable(executeMethodA())
               .ifPresent(() -> executeMethodB());
}
catch(Exception ex){
   ...
}
```

**Question:**

- How to handle **internally** an exception if was thrown by the main method executed in an Optional?

Comment: Are you looking for a `Try`/`Either` style type?

Answer (score 1):

Not only does it not exist, it's not possible to exist.

In the following expression `executeMethodA()` is evaluated, then the result is passed to `Optional.ofNullable`.

```
Optional.ofNullable(executeMethodA())
```

If the `executeMethodA` throws, no method on `Optional` is ever invoked. It has no means to create some kind of method chain.

[In Brian Goetz' own words](https://stuartmarks.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/con6851-api-design-v2.pdf):

> Optional is intended to provide a ***limited*** mechanism for library method
> ***return types*** where there is a clear need to represent "no result," and
> where using null for that is overwhelmingly ***likely to cause errors***.

It is not designed to replace every conditional branch in your application, and nor will it ever be designed to do that.

Comment: I see, but what about if `.ifException(ex -> { try/catch block})` would return a default value or either simply propagate the original exception or re-thrown as other Exception type.

Comment: @ManuelJordan I can't really word it any better than I already have. If the method throws, nothing makes it inside Optional. There is no possible chained method upon Optional that you can invent that would work.

Comment: @ManuelJordan Whenever code attempts to ["control the flow using exceptions"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why), the code smell alarm bell should ring ;) Hence why `Optional` (and other JDK library code) would not support that.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik there is no built-in mechanism for that. Also I do not think it is even intended to replace try-catch. One way would be to move the instantiating into a separate call e.g.

```
private Optional<YourObject> executeMethodA() {
    try {
        return Optional.of(YourObject);
    } catch (YourObjectException e) {
        // do whatever
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}

executeMethodA().ifPresent(() -> executeMethodB());
```

You could also make it more generic, but that's up to you.